# Case analysis with intros in Coq

Tags: coq

I want to understand the syntax `intros [|n].` in the proof below.

```
Lemma zero_or_succ :
  forall n : nat, n = 0 \/ n = S (pred n).
Proof.
  intros [|n].
  - left. reflexivity.
  - right. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

My understanding is that it fixes n and then does a case analysis on it. However, I was used to case analysis using destruct. Is this a shortcut to do that? How should I understand a case analysis `[H1 | H2]` that has the first branch empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.
What you are using here are called *intro patterns*.

```
intros [|n].
```

is equivalent to

```
intro n. destruct n as [|n].
```

You're basically giving names to the different arguments of constructors, using `|` to separate said constructors.
For natural numbers you have constructors `O` and `S`. The first one has no argument, while the second has one and we call it `n`.

If you had a boolean you could use `[|]` since neither `true` nor `false` take arguments.
Note that `intros []` is also possible and corresponds to `intro h. destruct h.` without naming the variables.
More generally you don't have to be exhaustive in naming variables.
`intros [|].`, `intros []` or `intros [|?]` work just as well for natural numbers (`?` allows you to state that there is a variable which you won't name, coq will give it one automatically).